# Closed-form of infinite continued fraction involving factorials

Tags: fractions, continued-fractions

Is there a closed form of this:

$$
1!+\dfrac{1}{2!+\dfrac{1}{3!+\dfrac{1}{4!+\ldots}}}
$$

Comment: It is interesting .  and can't see it.hope someone take some usefull                                   [Continued fraction]:http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ContinuedFraction

Comment: not too far from $459/314$

Comment: $1.461783355000579602560079367$ is the value of the number.

Comment: The inverse symbolic calculator cannot find a closed form for this.

Comment: $\large \frac{55099}{37693}$ is an approximation with an error of abot $10^{-12}$

Comment: I'd bet my head that number is trascendental.

Comment: At least it converges rapidly :)

Comment: @ajotatxe Careful with that bet or you might end up like Robespierre! (I guess "almost all" real numbers are transcendental, so you might be safe ...)

Comment: See [OEIS A$100608$](http://oeis.org/A100608).

Answer (score 1):

My 2 cents worth. Here is a Pascal program snippet that does Peter's job;
actually half of it due to Delphi's double precision limitations.
Backward recursion is the clue (again).

```
program Peter;

procedure fraction;
var
  a : double;
  f,k : integer;
begin
  f := 1*2*3*4*5*6*7*8*9*10;
  k := 10; a := f;
  while k > 1 do
  begin
    f := f div k;
    a := 1/a+f;
    k := k-1;
  end;
  Writeln(a);
end;

begin
  fraction;
end.
```

Output:

```
 1.46178335500058E+0000
```

Closed form? I don't think so.